# fit curve with fft and calculate it's derivatives

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis, matlab, fast-fourier-transform

Here is my issue:
I am trying an algorithm using FFT to fit and get a function's approximative in order and calculate its derivative in an easier way (for any data), but I get some discontinuity.
At first I am using the initial function: 
$$ y(\sigma, t_0) = \sin(\sigma) $$  with $-\pi \le  \sigma \le  \pi$ to try it.

After the FFT the function can be approximated by:
$$ y\left(\sigma ,t\right)=\sum _{k=0}^{N/2}[a_k\left(t\right)\sin\left(k\sigma \right)+b_k\left(t\right)\cos\left(k\sigma \right)].  $$

The first and second derivatives should be :

$$ y_{\sigma }=\sum _{k=1}^{N/2}k\left[a_k\left(t\right)\cos\left(k\sigma\right)-b_k\left(t\right)\sin\left(k\sigma \right)\right] $$

$$ y_{\sigma \sigma}=-\sum _{k=1}^{N/2}k^2\left[a_k\left(t\right)\sin\left(k\sigma \right)+b_k\left(t\right)\cos\left(k\sigma\right)\right],$$

but as you can see on my figure, some noise appears near $\sigma = 0$ for the first derivative and it becomes worse for the second one.

Does anyone have a solution to fix that issue? I am kind of lost now.

Thanks in advance.

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUn9I.jpg)

Here is my code

```
close all; clear all;
N=1024;   sigma = linspace(-pi,pi,N);     y= sin(sigma);

h=sum(y)/N;
    y = y-h;       

    cn = 2/N *fft(y);        % FFT to retriece the complex Fourier coeff
    cn= cn(1:N/2);          % taking half of the coeff because FFT is symmetric

    bk = real(cn);            ak = imag(cn); % fourier coefficient

%%% calculation of the initial function approximate by FFT
  for i=1:N
        yf(i) = 0; % initialisation
        for j=1:length(ak)
            jj=j-1;
            yf(i) = (yf(i) +( ak(j)*sin(jj*sigma(i) )+ bk(j)*cos(jj*sigma(i)) ));
        end 
end

%%% calculation of the first and second derivative in therms of sigma

for j = 1:N       
        Yo(j) = 0;         
        Yoo(j) = 0; 

    for l=2:length(ak)
        k=l-1;
        kk=k;
         Yo(j) = (Yo(j) + kk*( ak(l) * cos(k*sigma(j)) - bk(l) * sin(k*sigma(j)) ) );
         Yoo(j) = (Yoo(j) - kk^2 *( ak(l) * sin(k*sigma(j)) + bk(l) * cos(k*sigma(j)) ) );            
    end
end 


plot(sigma,yf);   hold on
plot(sigma,Yo)
xlabel('sigma');  ylabel('y')
hold off
```

Comment: My advice is to stop using DFT. It behaves badly with derivatives. I suggest just fit a quadratic locally and that gives you 1st and 2nd derivatives.

Comment: I don't see a figure.

Comment: I couldn't upload figures but basically for the first derivative I get a cosine function with a huge oscillation for sigma=0.        I will try with the quadrature as you recommended, the only thing is that I needed those Fourier coefficient to calculate other functions derivatives like X_sigma, it looks like this`$y_{sigma }=sum {k*[ak(t)cos(k*sigma)-bk * sin(k*sigma)]}` then my function x will be `x_{sigma }&=-1-sum {k*[akk(t)sin(k*sigma)+bk * cos(k*sigma)]}`